# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'semaphore' doesn't exist

Tags: database

I am having problems migrating my site to a production server. It's build in Drupal 7. I used the backup and migrate plugin to export the DB. The development server is Windows with Wamp installed and the production server is CentOS with Cpanel.

These are the errors I am getting:

> Error The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later. Error message PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view
>   not found: 1146 Table       'fosagams_co_za.semaphore' doesn't exist:
>   SELECT expire, value FROM   {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array (
>   [:name] => variable_init ) in    lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of
>   /home/balabalab/public_html/includes/lock.inc). Uncaught exception
>   thrown in shutdown function.
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table      'fosagams_co_za.semaphore' doesn't exist:
>   DELETE FROM  {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ;
>   Array (      [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =>
>   191980980751f69eddeb26b7.24464293 ) in  lock_release_all() (line 269
>   of /home/balabalab/public_html/includes/lock.inc).

I did however verify that the semaphore table exists. I am out of ideas, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you double checked the database settings in `settings.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem.
Then i realizez that when migrating, i copy and paste from old server. And when i opend the database on my new server and choose a table in it, it was emty giving me error: "table does not exist". So check out if it is importing the content of the data firt before continuing with your search.